# JAX-WS Endpoint bean creation fails with ServiceConstructionException

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, cxf, jax-ws

I am trying to publish a `webservice` with `spring-boot`

Here is how I have set it up.

I have an `interface` that has some `methods` say

```
@WebService
public interface FirstInterface
{
    @WebMethod
    void method1(@WebParam(name = "id") String id);
    void method2(@WebParam(name = "id2") String id);
}
```

I have another `interface` that has some more `methods`
and it extends `FirstInterface`

```
@WebService
public interface SecondInterface extends FirstInterface
{
    @WebMethod
    void method3(@WebParam(name = "id") String id);
    void method4(@WebParam(name = "id2") String id);
}
```

Now I have an implementation class that implements `SecondInterface`
and has an `endpointInterface` referring to my `SecondInterface` something like this:

```
@Service
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.somepackage.SecondInterface")
public class CallBackServicesImpl implements SecondInterface
{
    @Override
    //override all four methods here
}
```

Now I have a configuration class that is publishing these services

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig
{
    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), serviceImpl());
        endpoint.publish(SERVICE_NAME_PATH);
        return endpoint;
    }
```

}

**Problem:**  The `webservice` gets published with this setup with `endpointinterface` pointing to `FirstInterface` but only two methods will be available for use.

Now I all want four methods to be available for the client to use, so I point `endpointinterface` to `SecodInterface` and it start throwing exception saying `Error creating bean with name 'endpoint'`,`org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException`

Am I missing something basic here? How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @WebService annotation on impl class

Here is the working copy

**FirstInterface.java**

```
@WebService
public interface FirstInterface {

    @WebMethod
    void method1(@WebParam(name = "id") String id);
    @WebMethod
    void method2(@WebParam(name = "id2") String id);

}
```

**SecondInterface.java**

```
@WebService
public interface SecondInterface extends FirstInterface {

    @WebMethod
    void method3(@WebParam(name = "id") String id);

    @WebMethod
    void method4(@WebParam(name = "id2") String id);

}
```

Impl class

```
@Service
public class KPImpl implements SecondInterface {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KPImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void method3(String id) {

        LOG.info("Method3 {}", id);

    }

    @Override
    public void method4(String id) {
        LOG.info("Method4 {}", id);
    }

    @Override
    public void method1(String id) {
        LOG.info("Method1 {}", id);

    }

    @Override
    public void method2(String id) {

        LOG.info("Method2 {}", id);

    }

}
```

Finally configuration file

```
@Configuration
public class WsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Server getJaxWsServer(SpringBus bus, KPImpl impl) {

        final JaxWsServerFactoryBean serverFctry = new JaxWsServerFactoryBean();
        serverFctry.setAddress("/kp");
        serverFctry.setServiceBean(impl);
        serverFctry.setServiceClass(KPImpl.class);
        serverFctry.getFeatures().add(new LoggingFeature());
        return serverFctry.create();
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with this either, same exception.
besides what I really don't understand is that what is wrong with my way of doing it.

Comment: Can we see the pom.xml?

Comment: I have `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws` and `cxf-rt-transports-http` dependencies along with required sprint-boot dependencies.
Strange thins is that it works if the endpointinterface is referring to FirstInterface.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting may be full stack trace will help.

Comment: I have solved it, there was an issue with one of the return types of an interface method due to which the endpoint creation was getting failed.
It was a silly mistake.The exception was not clear so took a lot of time to catch it.
Thanks for the help though.